# Estimate for a $\operatorname{E}_1$ sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, logarithms, estimation, singularity

For $r>0$ we define
$$\operatorname{E}_1(r) := \int_{r}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt.$$
This defines a positive strictly decreasing function with logarithmic singularity at $r=0$. Breaking the integral at $t=1$ gives you the estimate
$$\operatorname{E}_1(r) \le \max(0,-\log(r))+e^{-r}.$$
I need to estimate
$$f(r):=\sum_{n =1}^\infty \operatorname{E}_1(n^2r).$$
Is there a $C>1$ with
$$f(r) \le C \operatorname{E}_1(r)$$
for all $r>0$? If so, what is the least such $C$?

Or do we have
$$
f(r)<-C\log(r)
$$
for some $C>1$ for small values of $r$?

Comment: No, I'd say $f(r)\sim\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{r}}$ for small $r$.

Comment: @qfwfq That's interesting. How would you show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, $$f(r)=\int^\infty_r\sum^\infty_{n=1}e^{-n^2t}\,\frac{dt}t.\tag1$$ But
$$\lim_{h\to0}\sum^\infty_{n=1}h\,e^{-n^2h^2}=\int^\infty_0e^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2,$$ with $h=\sqrt{t}$ we get
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}e^{-n^2t}\sim\frac12\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}t}.$$ Plugging this into (1), we have $$f(r)\sim\sqrt{\frac{\pi}r}.$$